# How to get particular post of salesforce chatter deskop using simple-salesforce API

Tags: salesforce1-app

I am need of getting particular user posts from chatter Desktop. I am able to login and get info on basis of built function but i am not able to get result of query due to error.

Query:

```
>>> sf.query("SELECT count() FROM Contact")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simple_salesforce\api.py", line 271, in qu
ery
    _exception_handler(result)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simple_salesforce\api.py", line 615, in _e
xception_handler
    raise exc_cls(result.url, result.status_code, name, response_content)
simple_salesforce.api.SalesforceMalformedRequest: Malformed request https://na3.
salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/query/?q=SELECT+count%28%29+FROM+Contact. Res
ponse content: [{u'errorCode': u'INVALID_TYPE', u'message': u"\nSELECT count() F
ROM Contact\n                    ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:21\nsObject type 'Cont
act' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to
append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the descri
be call for the appropriate names."}]
```

Please help me, Thanks in advance...

Comment: are you sure your user has access to the object ?

Comment: Yes, 100%, Because..  below code is not throwing any error.  'sf = Salesforce(instance_url='https://fa0.salesforce.com', session_id='')
sf = Salesforce(username='b.s@XXX.com', password='XXXX', security_token='zawdfJdexfFfjDQBMJrrCcYdoCA')'

Comment: Have you tried ``select count(id) from Contact``